# How to remove ALL metadata using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, wav

I have input file: `infile.mp3`
This file contains metadata (artist, genre, etc.)
I try remove all metadata to output a `.wav` file.

Yes! I found option:

> -map_metadata -1

But output is unexpected to me...

```
$ ffmpeg -i infile.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 \
                -ar 44100 -map_metadata -1 ./outfile.wav
```

OK!

```
$ ffprobe outfile.wav
Input #0, wav, from 'inp.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:04:00.47, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

You see? encoder metadata exists!

And in the `wav` header after "subchunk1_id" with "fmt " value I expect in "subchunk2_id" is the "data" value (clear expected example):

```
$ strings outfile.wav | more
RIFFFB
WAVEfmt
data
```

But it is not (LIST, INFOISFT, etc):

```
$ strings outfile.wav | more
RIFFFB
WAVEfmt 
LIST
INFOISFT
Lavf56.25.101
data
```

Well.. How to really remove all metadata from the output file?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg.
It says you can't remove completely all metadata.

Comment: @Martin -- the same result

Comment: As a side note, with Linux you can look at a binary file using `xxd <filename> | less` which better shows you the IFF hunks.

Answer (score 23):

```
-fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact
```

Comment: This was very useful for me as the goal of removing metadata was to make bitwise comparison possible.

Comment: Thank you @mzs. While this won't strip the existing metadata present in the original file, it will keep ffmpeg from adding it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to convert aiff files to a wav that python's pyglet package can read without dependencies

Comment: @mzs is this fflags part of ffmpeg?

Comment: Hi~ @mzs . I was try your answer. But It was not work. Can you help me to check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688450/how-to-use-ffmpeg-remove-all-metadata-include-duration-and-encoder ?

Comment: @Jun711 Yes, `fflags` is part of `ffmpeg`. A complete command would be `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c copy -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact output.m4a`