# How to use ffmpeg remove all metadata? Include DURATION and ENCODER

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

[image]

How to use ffmpeg remove all metadata? I was try the answer in [How to remove ALL metadata using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964861/how-to-remove-all-metadata-using-ffmpeg) .

But It was not work (as the picture). This is my command:

```sh
ffmpeg.exe  -i "source.mkv" -profile:v main -level 3.1 -b:v 1000K -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact -map_metadata -1 -bf 0 -vcodec copy -c:v libx264 -vf scale=320x320,crop=320:320:0:0 -strict -2 "VIDEO1.mkv" -y
```

I try use `freemake video converter` to convert (as the picture). The output video is no metadata. I don't know why it can do.

[image]

And Then I tried to use ffmpeg to convert the video converted using Freemake. Metadata is added again!

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I need to play in a device. If it has the metadata.It can't play correct.